# Парсинг динамических элементов через BS4 python

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Всем  доброго дня!

Недавно открыл для себя чудесную библиотеку BeautifulSoup для Парсинга сайтов, однако столкнулся с одной проблемой: тот контент на сайте, что мне нужен, как мне кажется, создается только в случае посещения сайта. При инспектировании элементов на браузере виден полный html код страницы со всем контентом, однако при парсинге его и вовсе нет.

Вот такой простенький код со ссылкой на сайт есть:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = 'https://afisha.ykt.ru'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

**Вопрос**: как в этом случае получить контент тега div с классом event?

Answer (score 2):

Либо выполнять тот же запрос, что делает и сайт для получения содержимого, либо использовать selenium

https://python-scripts.com/question/7270